# litElement use class variable in static style

Tags: styles, lit-element

I need to calculate same popover position in my litElement class. And next use it as style value. eg.:

```
export const defaultProps = {
  wrapperTop: 0,
}

export class Popover extends ScopedElementsMixin(LitElement) {

  ...
  static get properties() {
    return {
      wrapperTop: { type: String || Number, reflect: true},
    }
  }

  ...

 constructor() {
   super();

   this.wrapperTop = this.defaultProps.wrapperTop
 }

static get styles() {
  return css`
  .popover-wrapper {
     top: ${this.wrapperTop} //this.wrapperTop is undefined
   }`
 }

 calculateY () {
  //calculate Y depend on some element position
 }

 update() {
  calculateY()
 }

 ...
 
 return html`<div class="popoverWrapper"> ... </div>`
}
```

And I can't find some way to use this.wrapperTop in get static styles. It's undefined. There are some way to do this, or I have to use just style="" in render?

Answer (score 0):

Add `unsafeCSS` to your imports:

```
import { html, css, LitElement, unsafeCSS } from 'lit-element';
```

To use

```
static get styles() {
  return css`
  .popover-wrapper {
     top: ${unsafeCSS(this.wrapperTop)} //this.wrapperTop is undefined
   }`
}
```